# Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Tags: python

I'm trying to add noise (gaussian, salt/pepper, poisson and speckle) to an image using python (3.7) and opencv and then creating a numpy array, size 400 x 600, with zeros, slice it and put in the centre a white square, size 150 x 300, apply the "noisy" function and finally obtaining and plotting the original image with this function's four different kinds of noise.
My code is:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def noisy(noise_typ,image):
    """
     Parameters
    ----------
    image : ndarray
        Input image data. Will be converted to float.
    mode : str
        One of the following strings, selecting the type of noise to add:
    
        'gauss'     Gaussian-distributed additive noise.
        'poisson'   Poisson-distributed noise generated from the data.
        's&p'       Replaces random pixels with 0 or 1.
        'speckle'   Multiplicative noise using out = image + n*image,where
                    n is uniform noise with specified mean & variance.
    """
    # 1_GAUSSIAN NOISE --------------------------------------
    if noise_typ == 'gauss':
       if len(image.shape) == 3:
           FLAG_RGB = True
           row, col, ch = image.shape
       else:
           FLAG_RGB = False
           row, col = image.shape
           mean = 0
           var = 0.1
           sigma = var**0.5
       if FLAG_RGB:
           gauss = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (row, col, ch))
           gauss = gauss.reshape(row, col, ch)
       else:
           gauss = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (row, col))
           gauss = gauss.reshape(row, col)
       img_noisy = image + gauss
       return img_noisy
       
    # 2_SALT AND PEPPER NOISE -------------------------------
    elif noise_typ == 's&p':
        if len(image.shape) == 3:
            FLAG_RGB = True
            row, col, ch = image.shape
        s_vs_p = 0.5
        amount = 0.004
        out = np.copy(image)
        
        # Salt mode
        num_salt = np.ceil(amount * image.size * s_vs_p)
        coords = [np.random.randint(0, i - 1, int(num_salt)) for i in image.shape]
        out[coords] = 1
        
        # Pepper mode
        num_pepper = np.ceil(amount * image.size * (1. - s_vs_p))
        coords = [np.random.randint(0, i - 1, int(num_pepper))for i in image.shape]
        out[coords] = 0
        return out
    
    # 3_POISSON NOISE ---------------------------------------
    elif noise_typ == 'poisson':
        vals = len(np.unique(image))
        vals = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(vals))
        img_noisy = np.random.poisson(image * vals) / float(vals)
        return img_noisy
    
    # 4_SPECKLE NOISE --------------------------------------
    elif noise_typ == 'speckle':
        if len(image.shape) == 3:
            FLAG_RGB = True
            row, col, ch = image.shape
        else:
            FLAG_RGB = False
            row, col = image.shape
        if FLAG_RGB:
            gauss = np.random.randn(row, col, ch)
            gauss = gauss.reshape(row, col, ch)
        else:
            gauss = np.random.randn(row, col)
            gauss = gauss.reshape(row, col)
        img_noisy = image + image * gauss
        return img_noisy


# Create an numpy array, size 400 x 600, with zeros
imgarray = np.zeros([400,600],dtype=np.uint8)
# Slicing the array to put the inside square white
imgarray [125:275,150:450] = 255
noisy_gau = noisy(imgarray,'gauss')
noisy_sAp = noisy(imgarray,'s&p')
noisy_poi = noisy(imgarray,'poisson')
noisy_spe = noisy(imgarray,'speckle')

imgTitles = ['gauss', 's&p', 'poisson', 'speckle']
images = [noisy_gau, noisy_sAp, noisy_poi, noisy_spe]
for i in range(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i], 'gray')
    plt.title(imgTitles[i])
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.savefig('Comparison types of Noise.png')
plt.show()
```

I was expecting this:[expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oPPi.png)
The output I got:

```
runfile('C:/Users/megas/Desktop/Uni/6º/2º cuatri/Vision Artificial/Practicas/Lab 5/deliverable02.py', wdir='C:/Users/megas/Desktop/Uni/6º/2º cuatri/Vision Artificial/Practicas/Lab 5')
c:\users\megas\desktop\uni\6º\2º cuatri\vision artificial\practicas\lab 5\deliverable02.py:29: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if noise_typ == 'gauss':
c:\users\megas\desktop\uni\6º\2º cuatri\vision artificial\practicas\lab 5\deliverable02.py:49: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  elif noise_typ == 's&p':
c:\users\megas\desktop\uni\6º\2º cuatri\vision artificial\practicas\lab 5\deliverable02.py:69: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  elif noise_typ == 'poisson':
c:\users\megas\desktop\uni\6º\2º cuatri\vision artificial\practicas\lab 5\deliverable02.py:76: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  elif noise_typ == 'speckle':
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\megas\anaconda3\envs\Lab05\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\megas\desktop\uni\6º\2º cuatri\vision artificial\practicas\lab 5\deliverable02.py", line 106, in <module>
    plt.imshow(images[i], 'gray')

  File "C:\Users\megas\anaconda3\envs\Lab05\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 459, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\megas\anaconda3\envs\Lab05\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2657, in imshow
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\megas\anaconda3\envs\Lab05\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 459, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\megas\anaconda3\envs\Lab05\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1414, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\megas\anaconda3\envs\Lab05\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5487, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)

  File "C:\Users\megas\anaconda3\envs\Lab05\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 707, in set_data
    "float".format(self._A.dtype))

TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMMC9.png)
```

Comment: Your arguments are in the wrong order. Replace this: def noisy(image, noise_typ):

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didnt realise, shame on me ^^'